# Why does getRemoteHost() return an IP address upon deploying the application?

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, ibm-was

In my development environment, getRemoteHost() successfully returns the client's PC/machine name.  But once I deploy my application to our production environment, getRemoteHost() suddenly is returning the IP address.

Any thoughts on what needs to be done to make it always return the PC/machine name? It's a Java web application running on WAS 7.0.

Answer (score 8):

From the Java API

`java.lang.String getRemoteHost()`

`Returns the fully qualified name of the client or the last proxy that sent the request.
If the engine cannot or chooses not to resolve the hostname (to improve performance), this method returns the dotted-string form of the IP address.`

Edit: You can try resolving the host name like this

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipString);
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

Where `ipString` is the dotted-string form of the IP returned from the `getRemoteHost()` call.

Comment: Is there a way or setting to force it to always resolve the hostname?

Comment: That is, assuming you have correct PTR records and IP address is mapped to the correct DNS server.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Right. Thats why it is merely a "try" at resolving the hostname ;)